# Set default value for @Input in case that it's null from departure

Tags: angular

I have an "attribute" which gets its value form an "object". This "object" is null before user Login, so that "attribute" is null too and Angular CLI wouldn't compile my App.

The Error is:

> Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'attribute' since it isn't
>   a known property of 'component'.

Template:

```
<my-directive [attribute]="object.array.length"></my-directive>
```

"my-directive" Component:

```
@Input() attribute: number;
```

**So how can I prevent this error by setting a default value for my Attribute in  such case that the Object has not been set. So my Attribute will have a value anyway and my App would compile regardless of Object's Value.**

Comment: The error is caused when you didn't properly bind an Input to its html decoration. Not because of the value. Try changing name, maybe `attribute` is a reserved key

Comment: I changed the names for simplicity. the actual names are different and not reserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use the conditional property `?` operator in your template.

Change to:

```
<my-directive [someAttribute]="someObject?.array.length"></my-directive>
```

This will tell angular to try and access the `array` property only when the `someObject` is available.

Comment: You can also ensure that your object has a value with this : `@Input() attribute = 0;` : if the value is provided, it will override the default value, which is zero.

Comment: @ashish.gd Thanks Bro, Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default value like this:

```
@Input() attribute: number=0;
```

Comment: Thanks but ashish.gd answer is what i was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad you've found your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise the input this way:

```
@Input() attribute: number | null;
```

So, even if object is null you can initialise the attribute.